# RAML MimeType for text/plain

Tags: text, raml, mulesoft

Am trying to send a application/flatfile . (fixed width format) file in response back to consumer. how do i specify that in RAML 1.0

am trying to provide mime type for RAML which will be used in mulesoft . am building application/flatfile in dataweave 2.0 and want to send that back in response **as an attachment**. what mime type should i choose in body ? and for the consumer can he download the file , i see postman can do that while invoking (send and download)

who ever consume this should be able to get response as a file attachment and how do i mention the properties in raml for application/flatfile

```
/test:
  /sfdc:  
    /time:
      get:
        is: [client-id-required]
        responses: 
          200:
            body: 
              text/plain:
```

Answer (score 0):

The mime type of the response should be whatever the type of content being downloaded is.
In cases where the response's content type may vary, say the server may respond with a plain text, pdf or an octet stream, then the raml should look something like this:

```
responses: 
    200:
        body:
            text/plain:
            application/pdf:
            application/octet-stream:
```

And in addition to the Content-Type header, the http response should also have a Content-Disposition header with a value of "attachment".

Something like the following:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my_flat_file.txt"
```